# foreach loop not limited to counter as expected

Tags: php, loops

I am receiving data via a cURL method, and tat 'feed' (`$data`) contains eight posts (`$post`) tops. I need to apply some conditional logic to this feed (`if (!$postTypeExcl)`) and I only want to output four posts in total. I tried the following block, but that doesn't work. All posts are outputted, though they are restricted to `if (!$postTypeExcl)`. So the only thing that isn't working is the counter.

I deliberately placed the counter outside the `foreach` loop so that the engine wouldn't keep looping even if the counter has reached it max.

```
$counter = 0;
if ($counter < 4) {
    foreach ($data as $post) {
        $postTypeExcl = $post->getProperty('story');
        if (!$postTypeExcl) {
            // Output some HTML

            $counter++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why your if statement is out of the loop?

```
$counter = 0;

    foreach ($data as $post) {
        if ($counter >=4) break;
        $postTypeExcl = $post->getProperty('story');
        if (!$postTypeExcl) {
            // Output some HTML

            $counter++;
        }
    }
```

Something like that.

Answer (score 1):

This is your code:

```
$counter = 0;
if ($counter < 4) {
    // .. do something ...
}
```

0 is always less than 4, so "do something" happens. That's your loop then.

What you are looking for is `break`, to exit the loop:

```
foreach ($data as $post) {
    $postTypeExcl = $post->getProperty('story');
    if (!$postTypeExcl) {
        // Output some HTML

        $counter++;
    }
    if ($counter > 4) break;
}
```